# Config Server with RabbitMQ Connection Issue

Tags: spring-cloud, spring-rabbit

I have RabbitMQ running in cloud foundry and trying to connect from config server running in local, below is what configured in application.yml file

```
  spring 
      rabbitmq:
        host: xxxx
        vhost: xxxx
        port: 5672
        username: xxx
        password: xxx
```

throws below startup exception

```
org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Failed to start bean 'outputBindingLifecycle'; nested exception is org.springframework.amqp.AmqpTimeoutException: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:176) ~[spring-context-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.access$200(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:51) ~[spring-context-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor$LifecycleGroup.start(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:346) ~[spring-context-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.startBeans(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:149) ~[spring-context-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.onRefresh(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:112) ~[spring-context-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:852) ~[spring-context-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:541) ~[spring-context-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:766) ~[spring-boot-1.3.2.RELEASE.jar:1.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.createAndRefreshContext(SpringApplication.java:361) ~[spring-boot-1.3.2.RELEASE.jar:1.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307) ~[spring-boot-1.3.2.RELEASE.jar:1.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.test.SpringApplicationContextLoader.loadContext(SpringApplicationContextLoader.java:98) [spring-boot-1.3.2.RELEASE.jar:1.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:98) [spring-test-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:116) [spring-test-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:83) [spring-test-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:117) [spring-test-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:83) [spring-test-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:228) [spring-test-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:230) [spring-test-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289) [spring-test-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:291) [spring-test-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:249) [spring-test-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:89) [spring-test-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61) [spring-test-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70) [spring-test-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:193) [spring-test-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:283) [surefire-junit4-2.18.1.jar:2.18.1]
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeWithRerun(JUnit4Provider.java:173) [surefire-junit4-2.18.1.jar:2.18.1]
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:153) [surefire-junit4-2.18.1.jar:2.18.1]
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:128) [surefire-junit4-2.18.1.jar:2.18.1]
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.invokeProviderInSameClassLoader(ForkedBooter.java:203) [surefire-booter-2.18.1.jar:2.18.1]
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:155) [surefire-booter-2.18.1.jar:2.18.1]
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:103) [surefire-booter-2.18.1.jar:2.18.1]
Caused by: org.springframework.amqp.AmqpTimeoutException: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.support.RabbitExceptionTranslator.convertRabbitAccessException(RabbitExceptionTranslator.java:70) ~[spring-rabbit-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.AbstractConnectionFactory.createBareConnection(AbstractConnectionFactory.java:289) ~[spring-rabbit-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory.createConnection(CachingConnectionFactory.java:506) ~[spring-rabbit-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.ConnectionFactoryUtils$1.createConnection(ConnectionFactoryUtils.java:85) ~[spring-rabbit-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.ConnectionFactoryUtils.doGetTransactionalResourceHolder(ConnectionFactoryUtils.java:135) ~[spring-rabbit-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.ConnectionFactoryUtils.getTransactionalResourceHolder(ConnectionFactoryUtils.java:71) ~[spring-rabbit-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.doExecute(RabbitTemplate.java:1278) ~[spring-rabbit-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.execute(RabbitTemplate.java:1271) ~[spring-rabbit-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.execute(RabbitTemplate.java:1247) ~[spring-rabbit-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitAdmin.declareExchange(RabbitAdmin.java:126) ~[spring-rabbit-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.rabbit.RabbitMessageChannelBinder.declareExchange(RabbitMessageChannelBinder.java:713) ~[spring-cloud-stream-binder-rabbit-1.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.rabbit.RabbitMessageChannelBinder.bindProducer(RabbitMessageChannelBinder.java:617) ~[spring-cloud-stream-binder-rabbit-1.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.rabbit.RabbitMessageChannelBinder.bindProducer(RabbitMessageChannelBinder.java:111) ~[spring-cloud-stream-binder-rabbit-1.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.ChannelBindingService.bindProducer(ChannelBindingService.java:87) ~[spring-cloud-stream-1.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.BindableProxyFactory.bindOutputs(BindableProxyFactory.java:266) ~[spring-cloud-stream-1.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.OutputBindingLifecycle.start(OutputBindingLifecycle.java:58) ~[spring-cloud-stream-1.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:173) ~[spring-context-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    ... 38 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: null
    at com.rabbitmq.utility.BlockingCell.get(BlockingCell.java:77) ~[amqp-client-3.5.7.jar:na]
    at com.rabbitmq.utility.BlockingCell.uninterruptibleGet(BlockingCell.java:111) ~[amqp-client-3.5.7.jar:na]
    at com.rabbitmq.utility.BlockingValueOrException.uninterruptibleGetValue(BlockingValueOrException.java:37) ~[amqp-client-3.5.7.jar:na]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel$BlockingRpcContinuation.getReply(AMQChannel.java:367) ~[amqp-client-3.5.7.jar:na]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection.start(AMQConnection.java:293) ~[amqp-client-3.5.7.jar:na]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:647) ~[amqp-client-3.5.7.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.AbstractConnectionFactory.createBareConnection(AbstractConnectionFactory.java:273) ~[spring-rabbit-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
```

below is the dependency in pom.xml

```
 <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-bus-amqp</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

I can connect to the console with the information provided in the application.yml but not sure why it throws TimeoutException, Any input would be really helpful,

Answer (score 5):

`spring.rabbitmq.port` is for the AMQP client (defaults to 5672), not the management UI. What you have looks like a management UI port. It's not really clear from what you said where your rabbit broker is running, but it's unlikely to be on port 15672. The default is more likely to be correct.

Comment: thanks Dr, yeah its 5672 only i had copied as 15672. by the way broker runs on PCF, the actual issue was using vhost property, i used virtual-host instead and able to connect,